# Error":"source image 2208x2208 too small for Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png, requires at least 2732x2048 source file"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen, hybrid-mobile-app

I have the splash screen = 2208 x 2208. And app icon 192 X 192. I am using  `ionic1` but still I am running the command as `ionic cordova resource` command to generate app icon and splash screen.

In Android it's working fine. But when I did for iOS, it throws me this error :

> Error: encountered bad status code (400) for https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/transform
> body: {"Error":"source image 2208x2208 too small for Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png, requires at least 2732x2048 source file"}

I don't know what issues it was. I make the splash screen as correct size only but I don't know why it's not working for iOS.

I can update my ionic version to do the re work of my app.

## Update

```
<platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
       <!--  <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" /> -->
       <!--  <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" /> -->
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
```

Comment: You provide landscape mode in your app?

Comment: @nivesh shastri how to disable that landscape mode... i dont want now ...only potrait i need

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 21):

This error occurs due to wrong dimensions for the splash screen resource. You have a splash screen image in resources folder with dimensions 2208 X 2208 but based on [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/) it should be 2732 X 2732

Comment: I had the same issue, creating a 2732 x 2732 size image for splash.png and re-running the command worked.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the error was misleading and this solved the issue

Comment: And "icon" file must have "1024x1024px"

Comment: Yeah, so now what?

Answer (score 1):

The icon image's maximum dimensions should be 1024x1024 px.

The splash image's maximum dimensions should be 2732x2732 px.

Icon Image's Name Extention .PNG to .png transfer

Then Run $ionic cordova resources

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Check config.xml file and remove all entries of Landscape images in this file and again build your project.**

Put this line in config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Comment: can i disable the landscape mode. So that if user rotate phone also, it should not rotate ... ??... i will check this answer

Comment: Yes you can disable landscape mode see updated answer.

Comment: Check updated answer this enable portrait mode for both platform.

Comment: i tried you code.. now i got `"Error":"source image 2208x2208 too small for Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png, requires at least 2048x2732 source file"`

Comment: ist for ipad potrait

Comment: Post your config file

Comment: now its shwing `Error":"source image 2208x2208 too small for Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png, requires at least 2048x2732 source file`   so the erroe is on height with all ipad ?

Comment: now i am getting that error for this 2 potrait `<splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />`

Comment: remove this entries as well as not comment : ' <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" /> 
       <!--  <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" /> '

Comment: You have all image with accurate sizes

Comment: Remove all splash portrait entries in config file left only 2208 entry.

Comment: then if my app run in ipad, the =n splash screen will not shows know ??

Comment: You define entry for portrait (2208) or not?

Comment: Because in ios if you have only one large image, this is work for all devices (iphone or ipad).